# Is there a function $y=f(x)$ such that $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

The exponential function $y=e^x$ is its own derivative, the hyperbolic functions $y=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}, y= \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ are equal to their own second derivatives, and the trigonometric functions $y=sin(x)$, $y=cos(x)$ are equal to their own fourth derivatives. Is there a function that is equal to its own third derivative?

Comment: what do you mean by $\dfrac{d^3 y}{dx}$? Do you mean the third derivative? And what is $f(x)$? Do you mean $\dfrac{d^3 y}{dx^3}=y$?

Comment: Dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080016/function-whose-third-derivative-is-itself

Comment: Can you set up the characteristic equation belonging to $y'''=y$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122  Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'''-y=0$$
the characteristics equation is 
$$r^3-1=0$$
$$(r-1)(r^2+r+1)=0$$
$$r_1=1$$
$$r_{2,3}=-0.5+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$
so the general Solution is
$$y=c_1e^{1x}+e^{-0.5x}(c_2\cos\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x+c_3\sin\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The exponential function is!

Less trivially, if $\omega $ is a complex number satisfying $\omega^3 =1$, then $f (z) = e^{\omega z} $ is its own third derivative.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function that is equal to its own third derivative?

**Hint**. One may check that
$$
f(x):=ae^x +be^{-x/2} \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2x\right)+ce^{-x/2} \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2x\right)
$$ satisfies $f^{(3)}=f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}x}\sin(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}x)+c_3e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}x}\cos(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}x)$